# Should I use "does works" or "does work"?

Tags: word-choice, usage

Recently I started to create a new email for work purposes. I work independently as a computer technician, I wanted the email to reflect my personal name and that I do not one but several jobs on PC. I started with something like **lucaspcwork**@example.com, trying to say: work that Lucas does on PC. Then I thought about **lucaspcworks**@example.com, trying to say the works Lucas does on PC.

That made me wonder, what is the right way? "Lucas does works on PC" or "Lucas does work on PC". Or should I use the word "job/jobs" instead of "work/works".

Comment: Such a question will only invite opinion. Your email address isn't grammatically formed English. So this is just a matter of which one people like better. Please take a look at the [tour] and the [help] to see what sort of questions can be answered here.

Comment: @JamesK I think that the author's edit has focused the question enough that we can give an objective answer about "doing work" or "doing works".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A native speaker is not likely to understand **works** there as part of your email address to mean "tasks you perform" or "you perform multiple tasks" for two reasons:

1) works are deeds or large undertakings, not tasks

> The saintly person received near universal praise for her good works.
>
> The philanthropist's name was associated with many good works.

2) **works** is a synonym for "shop" or "factory", a place where things are made, and the word has come to be used in the software and computer businesses as part of company names to convey the sense that these sorts of hi-tech businesses are also places where things get made or fabricated.